# How can I disable connection messages in mongo shell

Tags: mongodb

when I connect to a mongodb server through shell I will get below output:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.0
connecting to: mongodb://localhost/admin
MongoDB server version: 3.4.0-rc4
Server has startup warnings:
2017-08-07T09:45:19.112+0900 I CONTROL  [main] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2017-08-07T09:45:19.112+0900 I CONTROL  [main]
>
```

How can I diable these message and just show the prompt? Do I need to disable it in mongo-shell or mongodb server?

Comment: Umm [`--quiet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-quiet) It's actually in the manual and in many answers here. I don't think it does or "should" suppress the warnings though. You really should not be running the shell as `root`. Apparently it does suppress the warnings.

Comment: `--quiet` should be set on mongo shell which is client side. Whether I can do it on the server side?